# Run Application without Holding up terminal

Tags: shell

If i wanted to run an application from the terminal (linux, ubuntu), how do I do so so that the terminal is still usable or that so if I close the terminal, the application still runs.

Answer (score 41):

If you just want to use the terminal interactively again, run the command in the background by appending `&` after the command:

```
some_command &
```

If you want the application to continue functioning after closing the terminal as well, use `nohup`:

```
nohup some_command &
```

All STDOUT and STDERR will be redirected to the file `$PWD/nohup.out`.

Or `disown`:

```
some_command & disown
```

Both `nohup` and `disown` will make `some_command` immune to `SIGHUP`.

Check `man nohup` and `help disown` to get more idea on these.

Comment: I never knew about 'help' thanks. BTW, 'help' is built into bash to provide help on bash inbuilt commands.

Comment: Wish these worked from the menu...

Comment: Thanks! And is there a way to reconnect to it interactively?